# Variable value randomly changes in node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have built a node.js app with this structure:

In app.js:

```
var myList = ['0'];

app.get('/webpage',function(req,res){
    console.log(myList);
    res.render('webpage.ejs', {exps: myList});
});
```

On "webpage" I can display `myList` and there is also a form that allows me to add elements to `myList`. Let's say I append '1' to `myList` through this form.

I have the following problem I don't know how to debug:

- locally on my computer, this app works fine: I can see `['0','1']` in my console each time I refresh "webpage".
- online on Heroku, when I refresh "webpage" sometimes I see `['0','1']` sometimes I see just `['0']` and a couple of refresh later I see `['0','1']` again: it is like `myList` randomly oscillates between its default value when the app was first launched and the value that was specified later.

I use the same npm and node versions locally and on heroku and the same versions of dependencies. To my knowledge I have the same environment locally and heroku, so I have no idea where this problem could be coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be running multiple instances of on Heroku, in which case each request might be assigned to a different instance, each with its own process and memory space.

I believe Heroku also shuts down instances after a period of inactivity, so that might be an issue too.

If you intend to persist something, how about storing it in a database?

Comment: you're right, two dynos were running at the same time on Heroku. I never started more than one though so I'm waiting for heroku's support to know more about this issue.